Cypress for Angular library project
I have an Angular library project where I have a lot of components that I use in a handful of Angular applications.
Now I want to start testing these components using Cypress component testing. Setting up Cypress with an Angular application is super easy, but trying to do it for a library project is definitely not.
I don't really have any code to show as all my efforts are leading to the same error which is:
Error: Could not resolve "@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/common.js". Do you have "@angular-devkit/build-angular" and "@angular-devkit/core" installed?
    at C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.11.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-dev-server\dist\helpers\angularHandler.js:106:19
    at Array.map ()
    at getAngularCliModules (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.11.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-dev-server\dist\helpers\angularHandler.js:100:151)
    at async getAngularCliWebpackConfig (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.11.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-dev-server\dist\helpers\angularHandler.js:159:101)
    at async angularHandler (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.11.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-dev-server\dist\helpers\angularHandler.js:205:27)
    at async getPreset (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.11.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-dev-server\dist\devServer.js:94:20)
    at async Function.devServer.create (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.11.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-dev-server\dist\devServer.js:111:61)
    at async C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.11.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-dev-server\dist\devServer.js:26:24

I've tried setting Cypress up both using the @cypress/schematic and by using npm install cypress --save-dev, to no avail.
I stumbled upon this github issue while trying to find information on how to accomplish what I want. Which talks about a library project needing an application set up in order to make it work but I have no clue how to do that and there are no examples provided either.
If anyone have succeeded in setting this up I would love some guidance!
I currently use Angular version 18 and Cypress version 13.

Some code illustrating the problem would be really useful (for those not using Angular every day)

First of all, seems you're using Cypresss 13.11.0 whilst latest is 13.12.0 at moment of writing this. This is relevant as 13.12.0 introduces Component Testing support for Angular v18
About setting it up, I've managed to setup Cypress component testing for Angular v18 by adding a dummy application to the workspace (ng g app dummy). This is because Cypress reads Angular application config to build the component and if there's no app, doesn't know which config to use. This is  mentioned in the GitHub issue you pointed out. This seems the easiest & low maintenance cost for now.
Checkout more details in this repository:
https://github.com/davidlj95/angular-lib-cypress-component-testing
Didn't manage to reproduce your specific error though. But hope that those 2 things solve your issue :)

Thanks @davidlj95! I will try to find the time to check your repo out and test the solution ASAP. I really appreciate the effort!

I tried it out and got it running! Huge thanks! I did have initial errors though when trying it on my existing project, but it turned out I had an old version of @angular-devkit/core installed which caused the error.

You can specify sourceRoot: 'projects/sample-lib/src/lib' in the devServer options to avoid having a dummy application.
From Angular - Options API and the source code for angularHandler, this are the minimum configuration I came up with to make a sample lib testable:
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "angular",
      bundler: "webpack",
      options: {
        projectConfig: {
          root: '',
          sourceRoot: 'projects/sample-lib/src/lib',
          buildOptions: {
            outputPath: 'dist/sample-lib',
          }
        }
      }
    },
    specPattern: "**/*.cy.ts",
  },
});



I think you got it running because of the root and sourceRoot, but projectType isn't actually a projectConfig valid option: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/v13.12.0/cli/types/cypress.d.ts#L3513-L3517 It is used when looking for default project in your angular.json in case no default project is defined https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/v13.12.0/npm/webpack-dev-server/src/helpers/angularHandler.ts#L47 But not as a Cypress config for Angular

Which is why it doesn't appear either in the Cypress documentation about Angular options for Component Testing: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/angular/overview#Options-API

Davidj95 - the type for projectType is here

It defaults to application here which is why your dummy application hack is required if you don't supply the proper configuration.

Yeah the type is there but it refers to the Angular's project configuration options in angular.json. That's why it's called AngularJsonProjectConfig. I mean, this one: https://angular.dev/reference/configs/workspace-config#project-configuration-options. It doesn't default to application in the mentioned line. What code does there is to look for a project with type application in angular.json in case there's no defaultProject defined. There's no assignment, so no default.
